# Calling C++ from a for loop in python

Tags: python, c++

I'm calling cuda-convnet2 (a deep learning program) inside a loop in python. As cuda_convnet2 has C++ modules alongside with python modules, when I call the cuda-convnet2 inside a loop, it seems that the C++ module doesn't terminate after each iteration and causes issues. C++ module could be found at this link:
https://github.com/akrizhevsky/cuda-convnet2/blob/master/cudaconvnet/src/pyconvnet.cu
you could observe that in line 39 it generates a null model. line 67 is called from cuda-convnet2 python module to initialize a neural network model. If I call cuda-convnet2 only once, everythind is fine. But when I call it inside a for loop, after the first iteration of loop executes successfully, in second iteration I get the following error from my c++ module:

src/pyconvnet.cu:68: PyObject* initModel(PyObject*, PyObject*): Assertion `model == NULL' failed.

Any Idea what should I do?

for more detailed info:

This is the python module called convnet.py: 
https://github.com/akrizhevsky/cuda-convnet2/blob/master/convnet.py
This modele, calles the constructor from **main** (line 288), which then calles the costructor of IGPUmodel class in line 106(IGPUmodel class here https://github.com/akrizhevsky/cuda-convnet2/blob/master/python_util/gpumodel.py), and in this file line 100 opens the way to C++ module by calling init_model_lib() function defined in convnet.py line 114. 
I made small changes to this script (deleted **main** because I have my own **main**) and I copied line 288 and 289 to my own script:

```
def try_params(n_resources,params,op,load_dic):
        validation_frequency = 4
        if n_resources<4:
            validation_frequency=1
        model = ConvNet(op, load_dic,n_resources,validation_frequency)
        result = model.start()
        return result
```

I call this function inside a for loop:

```
for t in T:
      self.counter += 1
      start_time = time()                                
      result = self.try_params( n_iterations, t,self.op,self.load_dic )                                                       
      assert( type( result ) == dict )
      assert( 'loss' in result )
```

Comment: Please share the code used to call the module.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal just edited.